# Change Web.config depending on URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, web-config

I have a net mvc website and I want to change the web.config file dynamically depending on the incoming url. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: A website works based on the configurations in the web.config. How a website can change it's configuration itself?

Comment: I spoke to a senior developer friend at Microsoft and he confirmed that you can't do it.

Comment: Describe specifically what you are trying to accomplish and see if anybody can offer an alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own config files and branch it based on the URL but you will have to read as a XML file and will not be able to exploit the configuration namespace.